# Unable to fetch Docker images with token authenication for latest ecr images but for later images it works fine

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, yaml, amazon-ecr

So I am to authenticate with a token for my later images (2 days old) I pushed to ecr but not my latest images.

So here's the deal I create a container that runs a script before to authenticate a user, then on completion, it exits and then the next two containers run.

I use GitHub actions to push my images to ecr

Steps I've taken:
-logout and login aws login works but I need to use a [token-based auth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ECR.html)
-deleted stagnant containers
-tried multiple old images - works
-tried multiple new images - doesn't work
-tried looking through the diffs between the working and non-working images -- the biggest diff is a console.log and reverting back those changes still makes it not work
-turned my computer off and on

My questions:
-Could in some way a docker image get corrupted and not allowed to get pulled down?
-Is there a way to get some logs on what went wrong?
-Am I missing something? I'm relatively new to docker I come from a serverless background

Sample docker yaml file: I replaced my account id and obviously my token

```yaml
version: '3'
networks:
  ocd:
    name: ocd-network
services:
  pre-script:
    container_name: pre-script
    image: docker:19.03.13
    entrypoint: /bin/sh -c
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    command:
      - >-
        echo
        "token password"
        | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin
        {accountId}.dkr.ecr.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com && exit 0
  ocd-mgmt:
    container_name: ocd-mgmt-service
    image: >-
      {accountId}.dkr.ecr.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com/ocd:748031c8e84e1b446b1f33ab44c8850a3f85c942
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    networks:
      - ocd
      - default
    depends_on:
      - pre-script
    init: true
  ocd-api:
    container_name: ocd-api-service
    image: >-
      {accountId}.dkr.ecr.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com/ocd-api:65ba09d73f2de399f23794c54e98cdf067cd78ae
    ports:
      - '3001:3001'
    networks:
      - ocd
      - default
    depends_on:
      - pre-script
    init: true
```